# SQL SUM of Article-Prizes

Tags: sql, ms-access

i'm an absolute newbie in SQL and want to add up all the Sums of the Articles * ordered amount to a final prize. I tried to calculate the Articles * amount to the "Gesamtpreis" and then the Method SUM() to sum up all the "Gesamtpreis". Dont worry, the SQL-Code is auto-generated by Access.

Main Problem:

```
[Einzelpreis]*[Anzahl] AS Gesamtpreis, SUM(Gesamtpreis) AS FinalPreis
```

Whole Code:

```
SELECT Kunden.Kundennr
    , Kunden.Nachname
    , Kunden.Vorname
    , Kunden.Straße
    , Kunden.PLZ
    , Kunden.Ort
    , Bestellung.Bestellnr
    , Bestellung.Bestelldatum
    , Bestelldetails.Artikelnr
    , Bestelldetails.Anzahl
    , Artikel.Artikelname
    , Artikel.Einzelpreis
    , Artikel.Hersteller
    , [Einzelpreis]/119*19 AS MwStPreis
    , [Einzelpreis]-[MwStPreis] AS EinzelpreisNetto
    , [Einzelpreis]*[Anzahl] AS Gesamtpreis
    , SUM(Gesamtpreis) AS FinalPreis
FROM Kunden INNER JOIN
    (
        (Artikel INNER JOIN
            Bestelldetails ON Artikel.Artikelnr = Bestelldetails.Artikelnr
          ) INNER JOIN Bestellung ON Bestelldetails.Bestelldetailnr = Bestellung.Bestelldetailnr
    ) ON Kunden.Kundennr = Bestellung.Kundennr;
```

Comment: And your question is? How to use aggregate functions (like `sum()`) on MS Access/SQL? Do you got some error? (Hint - you should to use `group by` and maybe subqueries too.)

Comment: i got an error that kundennr isnt part of an aggregate function but it works without the sum() function.. and if i add Kundennr to an aggregate function, the error says nachname isnt part of an aggregate function.

Comment: when you use aggragate functions you need to use group by

Comment: so i have to write every select into the group by?.. that would work but now the finalpreis is only the last gesamtpreis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an aggregate function (e.g. `SUM()`, `COUNT()`, etc.), you need to group by every other field which is not part of an aggregate function in that query. For your case, it would be like this:

```sql
SELECT Kunden.Kundennr
    , Kunden.Nachname
    , Kunden.Vorname
    , Kunden.Straße
    , Kunden.PLZ
    , Kunden.Ort
    , Bestellung.Bestellnr
    , Bestellung.Bestelldatum
    , Bestelldetails.Artikelnr
    , Bestelldetails.Anzahl
    , Artikel.Artikelname
    , Artikel.Einzelpreis
    , Artikel.Hersteller
    , [Einzelpreis]/119*19 AS MwStPreis
    , [Einzelpreis]-[MwStPreis] AS EinzelpreisNetto
    , [Einzelpreis]*[Anzahl] AS Gesamtpreis
    , SUM([Einzelpreis]*[Anzahl]) AS FinalPreis
FROM Kunden INNER JOIN
    (
        (Artikel INNER JOIN
            Bestelldetails ON Artikel.Artikelnr = Bestelldetails.Artikelnr
          ) INNER JOIN Bestellung ON Bestelldetails.Bestelldetailnr = Bestellung.Bestelldetailnr
    ) ON Kunden.Kundennr = Bestellung.Kundennr
GROUP BY Kunden.Kundennr
    , Kunden.Nachname
    , Kunden.Vorname
    , Kunden.Straße
    , Kunden.PLZ
    , Kunden.Ort
    , Bestellung.Bestellnr
    , Bestellung.Bestelldatum
    , Bestelldetails.Artikelnr
    , Bestelldetails.Anzahl
    , Artikel.Artikelname
    , Artikel.Einzelpreis
    , Artikel.Hersteller
    , [Einzelpreis]/119*19
    , [Einzelpreis]-[MwStPreis]
```

EDIT: If you are looking for the SUM of all entries to appear on each entry, then you could do that like this:

```sql
SELECT Kunden.Kundennr
    , Kunden.Nachname
    , Kunden.Vorname
    , Kunden.Straße
    , Kunden.PLZ
    , Kunden.Ort
    , Bestellung.Bestellnr
    , Bestellung.Bestelldatum
    , Bestelldetails.Artikelnr
    , Bestelldetails.Anzahl
    , Artikel.Artikelname
    , Artikel.Einzelpreis
    , Artikel.Hersteller
    , [Einzelpreis]/119*19 AS MwStPreis
    , [Einzelpreis]-[MwStPreis] AS EinzelpreisNetto
    , [Einzelpreis]*[Anzahl] AS Gesamtpreis
    , [Total].[Total] AS [FinalPreis]

FROM (((((Kunden
INNER JOIN Bestellung ON Kunden.Kundennr = Bestellung.Kundennr)
INNER JOIN Bestelldetails ON Bestellung.Bestelldetailnr = Bestelldetails.Bestelldetailnr)
INNER JOIN Artikel ON Bestelldetails.Artikelnr = Artikel.Artikelnr)
INNER JOIN (

    SELECT Kunden.Kundennr, 1 AS [Key]
    FROM Kunden

) AS [Joiner] ON Kunden.Kundennr = [Joiner].Kundennr)
INNER JOIN (

    SELECT 1 AS [Key], SUM(Artikel.Einzelpreis*Bestelldetails.Anzahl) AS [Total]
    FROM Artikel
    INNER JOIN Bestelldetails ON Artikel.Artikelnr = Bestelldetails.Artikelnr

) AS [Total] ON [Joiner].[Key] = [Total].[Key])
```

EDIT: If you are looking for the sum of entries for each Kunden:

```sql
SELECT Kunden.Kundennr
    , Kunden.Nachname
    , Kunden.Vorname
    , Kunden.Straße
    , Kunden.PLZ
    , Kunden.Ort
    , Bestellung.Bestellnr
    , Bestellung.Bestelldatum
    , Bestelldetails.Artikelnr
    , Bestelldetails.Anzahl
    , Artikel.Artikelname
    , Artikel.Einzelpreis
    , Artikel.Hersteller
    , [Einzelpreis]/119*19 AS MwStPreis
    , [Einzelpreis]-[MwStPreis] AS EinzelpreisNetto
    , [Einzelpreis]*[Anzahl] AS Gesamtpreis
    , [Total].[Total] AS [FinalPreis]

FROM ((((Kunden
INNER JOIN Bestellung ON Kunden.Kundennr = Bestellung.Kundennr)
INNER JOIN Bestelldetails ON Bestellung.Bestelldetailnr = Bestelldetails.Bestelldetailnr)
INNER JOIN Artikel ON Bestelldetails.Artikelnr = Artikel.Artikelnr)
INNER JOIN (

    SELECT Kunden.Kundennr, SUM(Artikel.Einzelpreis*Bestelldetails.Anzahl) AS [Total]
    FROM (((Kunden
    INNER JOIN Bestellung ON Kunden.Kundennr = Bestellung.Kundennr)
    INNER JOIN Bestelldetails ON Bestellung.Bestelldetailnr = Bestelldetails.Bestelldetailnr)
    INNER JOIN Artikel ON Bestelldetails.Artikelnr = Artikel.Artikelnr)
    GROUP BY Kunden.Kundennr

) AS [Total] ON Kunden.Kundennr = [Total].Kundennr)
```

EDIT: If you are looking for the sum of entries for each Kunden and Bestellung:

```sql
SELECT Kunden.Kundennr
    , Kunden.Nachname
    , Kunden.Vorname
    , Kunden.Straße
    , Kunden.PLZ
    , Kunden.Ort
    , Bestellung.Bestellnr
    , Bestellung.Bestelldatum
    , Bestelldetails.Artikelnr
    , Bestelldetails.Anzahl
    , Artikel.Artikelname
    , Artikel.Einzelpreis
    , Artikel.Hersteller
    , [Einzelpreis]/119*19 AS MwStPreis
    , [Einzelpreis]-[MwStPreis] AS EinzelpreisNetto
    , [Einzelpreis]*[Anzahl] AS Gesamtpreis
    , [Total].[Total] AS [FinalPreis]

FROM ((((Kunden
INNER JOIN Bestellung ON Kunden.Kundennr = Bestellung.Kundennr)
INNER JOIN Bestelldetails ON Bestellung.Bestelldetailnr = Bestelldetails.Bestelldetailnr)
INNER JOIN Artikel ON Bestelldetails.Artikelnr = Artikel.Artikelnr)
LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT Kunden.Kundennr, Bestellung.Bestellnr, SUM(Artikel.Einzelpreis*Bestelldetails.Anzahl) AS [Total]
    FROM (((Kunden
    INNER JOIN Bestellung ON Kunden.Kundennr = Bestellung.Kundennr)
    INNER JOIN Bestelldetails ON Bestellung.Bestelldetailnr = Bestelldetails.Bestelldetailnr)
    INNER JOIN Artikel ON Bestelldetails.Artikelnr = Artikel.Artikelnr)
    GROUP BY Kunden.Kundennr, Bestellung.Bestellnr

) AS [Total] ON Kunden.Kundennr = [Total].Kundennr AND Bestellung.Bestellnr = [Total].Bestellnr)
```

Comment: yeah that works, but now the FinalPreis is just the last Gesamtpreis not the sum of all..

Comment: Replace `    , [Einzelpreis]*[Anzahl] AS Gesamtpreis
    , SUM(Gesamtpreis) AS FinalPreis` with this single line `, SUM([Einzelpreis]*[Anzahl]) AS FinalPreis`.

Comment: I think @Gustav is correct - I've updated the answer. It depends on whether you're looking for the sum of each group, or if you want the sum of all entries shown on each row.

Comment: still the same issue, cause i want to add up all the Gesamtpreis to a final sum, what means i wanna get the whole prize of every article * their amount together. It should show the gesamtpreis in the bill for each article * amount and the whole prize of every articles*amount together

Comment: You must exclude _all_ the GROUP BYs holding factors of FinalPreis.

Comment: Are you sure you wish to use sum in the same query that, as far as I can tell, is for listing all entries? I ask because if you intend to display a particular field, e.g. Artikel.Einzelpreis, then using it in a SUM() is not going to make any difference to the result.

Comment: idk im new to sql.. just want to get the whole prize of the bill for my report :(

Comment: Then use a subquery to calculate the sum - or let the report do the summing, much easier.

Comment: For example, the way the query is at the moment, it seems to me that Gesamtpreis will equal FinalPreis every time. So the question is, how should FinalPreis be different from Gesamtpreis (don't worry about the query, but what should it mean)?

Comment: it should be the addition of every gesamtpreis (so every gesamtpreis of every article)

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer to also include this approach. Hopefully it works for you :)
It is true that if you are going to use this query in a report, there are built in [methods](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/summing-in-reports-ad4e310d-64e9-4699-8d33-b8ae9639fbf4) to do that too, instead of in the query.

Comment: it works perfectly thanks! is it possible to get the finalpreis of specific customers (kunden) ? so that i could choose a customer for the bill and not all customers together like now?

Comment: Yes, I've added that to the bottom of the answer, too :)

Comment: it says syntax error in from clause :( but still thanks!

Comment: Ah! My mistake. Hopefully now it works.
By looking at this last query, you should be able to gain some understanding of how it is structured so that, with some practice, if you later wanted to group by a different field instead, then you would see where to change it :)

Comment: hello again, is there any way to do the same thing for each custommer + seperated for each bill (table bestellung with Bestellnr as primary key)? :) i mean that its the total amount spent per customer of a specific bill

Comment: Hello! Yes, I've added this to the answer, so you can see how :) If you look at the end of the query, there is a sub-query that is calculating the totals. At the end of that, there is a `GROUP BY` statement - what this means is: calculate a new total each time the values of any of those fields change. So, we need both `Kunden.Kundennr` (customer no) and `Bestellung.Bestellnr` (bill no) there - for each customer and bill, we want the total. We then join this subquery to the main query also using `Bestellnr` - so that the correct total is displayed for each combination of customer and bill. 